# datepicker - populate field after selecting month/year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the JQuery UI datepicker plugin with

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true
```

But the text field that holds the date only updates when the user actually clicks a day. If the user selects a month and year and then clicks outside the datepicker popup, I want the field to contain the first day of the month and year selected.

Currently the text field doesn't update unless the user actually clicks a particular day. Can anyone familiar with the plugin tell me if there is a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could populate the text of the field yourself by defining the onChangeMonthYear callback function
From the docs:

onChangeMonthYear: Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker moves to a new month and/or year. The function receives the selected year, month (1-12), and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the onChangeMonthYear event as an init option.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { ... }
});
```

so this is what you would want:

```
  $('.selector').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { 
       $(this).val(month + "/" + year);
   }
});
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/GDvEk/)

Answer (score 1):

mybe you can use something like this:

```
 $('.selector').datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
       var day = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();
       $(this).datepicker( "setDate", month+'/'+day+'/'+year);
    }
 });
```

Be carefully with location date format.

Complete example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/FagGK/

Comment: I think you meant just `$(this).datepicker("setDate", month + '/01/' + year);` in the callback, `$(this).datepicker('getDate')` will be `null`. http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FagGK/1/